# Authentification HTTP in PHP

Tags: php, http, basic-authentication

I would like to authenticate my thanks to php on a free API. 
Here is the link in French: 
[here](https://wiki.jvflux.com/Documentation_de_l'API_Jeuxvideo.com)

```
Login: appandr, password: e32!cdf
```

I am completely lost, can you help me please? 
That's what I started, but I do not know if I have good yet.

```
<?php
    $username = 'appandr';
    $password = 'e32!cdf';
    $stamp = time();
    $salt= 'OpX234';

    // md5(pseudo + motDePasse + "OpX234" + stamp)
    $hash = md5($username+$password+$salt+$stamp);
?>
```

Then how do you launch the application directly at the opening of the page. 
Envous thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Simply with simplexml_load_file()